# Highstock: custom tooltip ignored after zooming out

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

I have been working with highcharts/highstock for a while now and recently observed a behavior which I cannot understand. This is about the highstock Option [`tooltip.xDateFormat`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.xDateFormat), which allows custom rendering of the "date part" of the tooltip.

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('chart', {
  series: [ { data: series_data } ],
  tooltip: {
     xDateFormat: "test custom date"
  }
}
```

[image]

In practice, I use this option with format strings rather than hard-coded strings, but that is not relevant for this question. The unusual thing is, that after zooming out, the custom format is suddenly ignored and replaced by the default format.

[image]

It seems there is some kind of cutoff depending on the number of shown points. Zooming in again makes the tooltip switch back to the custom format.

A live example is available here: https://jsfiddle.net/GregorDeCillia/5hj6r1ft/9/

Has anyone experienced a similar behavior in the past? I am fairly familiar with the API reference of highcharts but can't seem to find any explanation why this happens. My goal is to prevent the default format (`Week from Monday, Jun 5, 2017`) from kicking in and have my custom format active at all times.

What I've tried

- Customize [`tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats.week) but again, the default week format is used after zooming out
- Use [`xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.week) but this only affects the rendering of the axis labels, not the tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by data-grouping feature. You can disable it or define a custom format for each time span.

```
  series: [{
    data: data,
    dataGrouping: {
      enabled: false,
      ...
    }
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yor987mt/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.dateTimeLabelFormats

Comment: Thank you so much! When I was searching the API reference for `dateTimeLabelFormats`, I actually got a hit for `dataGrouping` but immediately dismissed that as an option, because I couldn't see any relevance. Silly me :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a workaround using [`fooltip.formatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.formatter) which allows to define a tooltip for both the series and the dates using a callback function which returns an array of the form `[date, y1, y2, ...]`.

```js
tooltip: {
    formatter: _ => ['test custom date', 'custom y']
}
```

In my case, I now reuse the default formatter for the y value but replace the logic to format the dates

```js
tooltip: {
    formatter: function(tooltip) {
         let tt = tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);
         tt[0] = 'test custom date';
         return tt;
    }
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/GregorDeCillia/5hj6r1ft/58/